# How to contrain a view programmatically to parent in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to create a TextView (or any other view) programatically using the constraint layout. The textView would look like this in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test "
    android:textSize="19sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.16"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

So it should be constrained to the parents in all sides and then I can use the bias parameters to change its position dynamically. How can I implement this? I had a look at the answers given here [ConstraintLayout: change constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically) but there the objects are not constrained to the parents and no vertical and horizontal bias is used to position it dynamically as I am intending. Any idea if and how this would be possible within a Fragment (I use the Single-Activity Multiple-Fragments approach)?

**Update**:
I could now insert a custom view (instead of a TextView) inside a constrained layout programmatically. However, setting the orientation using the code      `constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(view.getId(), 0.56f);`does not have any effect (no mather, which numbers I use). The custom view is always at the top left corner.

Here you can see the code of the whole fragment(I denoted the important part):

```
public class Test extends Fragment implements Runnable {

    /*
    Game variables
     */

    public static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 100;
    public static final int TIME_OF_A_LEVEL_IN_SECONDS = 90;
    private int currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private FragmentGameBinding binding;

    private boolean viewHasBeenCreated = false;


    public Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentGameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        container.getContext();
        viewHasBeenCreated = true;
        startRound();
        return binding.getRoot();


    }

    public void startRound () {
        currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS =TIME_OF_A_LEVEL_IN_SECONDS * 1000;
        updateScreen();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

    }
    private void updateScreen() {
        binding.textViewTimeLeftValue.setText("" + currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS/1000);

        /*
        IMPORTANT PART: This should create a simple custom UI element
         */
        View view = new View(getActivity());
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        Drawable dr = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.light_bulb_layer_list);
        view.setBackground(dr);
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(view.getId(), 0.56f);
        constraintSet.setVerticalBias(view.getId(), 0.5f);
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        constraintLayout.addView(view);
    }

    private void countDownTime(){
        currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS = currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS -DELAY_MILLIS;
        updateScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(viewHasBeenCreated) {
            countDownTime();
        }
```

Any ideas why setting the horizontal or vertical orientation in the constraint layout does not have any effect?

Comment: The view must be added before cloning the constraints.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks for your answer. When I set `constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);` at the very end after `constraintLayout.addView(view);` nothing changes. The custom view is on the left top corner and setting the horizontal or vertical orientation in the constraint layout still does not have any effect. I also tried to set `constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);` and changed the order of some statements. Either nothing happenns (changing the orientation does not have any effect) or the custom view covers the whole display.

Comment: Your posted code is OK. You just need to move the `addView()` just _before_ cloning.  You want the id of the added view to be known to the constraint set.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cheticamp for your tremendous help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs there is a `PARENT_ID` in the [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#PARENT_ID) to use as the ID of constraints.

Also set `setHorizontalBias` and `setVerticalBias` methods as well.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264822/2373819) of you referenced slashdot question shows you how to use a [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#PARENT_ID)